# Overwriting global char array vs global char pointer in a loop in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

I have an infinite while loop, I am not sure if I should use a char array or char pointer. The value keeps getting overwritten and used in other functions. With a char pointer, I understand there could be a memory leak, so is it preferred to use an array?

```
char *recv_data = NULL;

int main(){
.....
  while(1){
   .....
   recv_data = cJSON_PrintUnformatted(root);

  .....
  
  }
}
```

or

```
char recv[256] = {0};

int main(){
.....
  while(1){
   .....
   strcpy(recv, cJSON_PrintUnformatted(root));

  .....
  
  }
}
```

Comment: The second version has the memory leak, since you can never free the array returned by the function.

Comment: Are you the one implementing the `cJSON_PrintUnformatted()` function? Or is it a given and you must use it?

Comment: @einpoklum `cJSON_PrintUnformatted()` is a standard JSON/cJSON function to print a cJSON object/item, it returns a pointer to char

Comment: C doesn't have a "standard" JSON library... are you sure you're using a good one? I'm not an expert on them, but have you considered alternatives? [This one](https://github.com/json-c/json-c) is pretty popular.

Answer (score 3):

The first version should be preferred.

1. It doesn't have a limit on the size of the returned string.
2. You can use `free(recv_data)` to fix the memory leak.

The second version has these misfeatures:

1. The memory returned from the function can't be freed, because you never assigned it to a variable that you can pass to `free()`.
2. It's a little less efficient, since it performs an unnecessary copy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I use free() right after `recv_data = cJSON_PrintUnformatted(root);`, won't there be a seg_fault in the next iteration of `while` loop when trying to set 'recv_data' again?

Comment: No, because the next iteration calls the function again, which allocates another array.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by _allocates another array_, could you please clarify further? Is it because it is a global pointer? Also I have to access `recv_data` in another function. This while(1) runs in a thread and I have another thread where I read `recv_data` and print its value. So freeing it and setting it to NULL wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: I assume that `cJSON_PrintUnformatted(root);` is calling `malloc()` internally to create the data that it returns the pointer to. So every time you call it, it allocates fresh memory for that JSON object.

Comment: That's why there's a memory leak if you don't free it.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. But I want to retain a global value of cJSON_PrintUnformatted(). Every iteration in the loop, I will have something like `char *data = cJSON_PrintUnformatted(root); free(data); data = NULL;` How to store it in the global value `recv_data`?

Comment: If you want to retain all the values you need multiple variables. You could use an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238339/discussion-between-bvj0412-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

Based on how you used it, the `cJSON_PrintUnformatted` returns a pointer to a char array. Since there are no input arguments, it probably allocates memory inside the function dynamically. You probably have to `free` that memory. So you need the returned pointer in order to deallocate the memory yourself.

The second option discards that returned pointer, and so you lost your only way to free the allocated memroy. Hence it will remain allocated -> memroy leak.

But of course this all depends on how the function is implemented. Maybe it just manipulates a global array and return a pointer to it, so there is no need to free it.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the second version has a memory leak, as @Barmar points out.

However, even if you were to fix the memory leak, you still can't really use the first version of your code: With the first version, you have to decide at compile-time what the maximum length of the string returned by `cJSON_PrintUnformatted()`. Now,

- If you choose a value that's too *low*, the `strcpy()` function would exceed the array bounds and corrupt your stack.
- If you choose a value that's so high as to be safe - you might have to exceed the amount of space available for your program's stack, causing a [Stack Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) (yes, like the name of this site). You could fix that using a [`strncpy()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncpy.htm), giving the maximum size - and then what you'd have is a truncated string.

So you really don't have much choice than using whatever memory is pointed to by the `cJSON_PrintUnformatted()`'s return value (it's probably heap-allocated memory). Plus - why make a copy of it when it's already there for you to use? Be lazy :-)

PS - What should really happen is for the `cJSON_PrintUnformatted()` to take a buffer and a buffer size as parameters, giving its caller more control over memory allocation and resource limits.